# conditional counting but no NA

Tags: r, count, data.table

i have a data frame like that

```
library(data.table)
mydata<-
data.table(comname=c("hon","hon","hon","acer","acer","acer","acer","acer","acer"),
oversea=c(1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0),
year=c(1991,1992,1993,1981,1982,1983,1983,1984,1985),
hopecount=c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,2,2))

   comname oversea year hopecount
1:     hon       1 1991         0
2:     hon       0 1992         0
3:     hon       1 1993         1
4:    acer       1 1981         0
5:    acer       0 1982         0
6:    acer       1 1983         1
7:    acer       1 1983         1
8:    acer       1 1984         2
9:    acer       0 1985         2
```

i count the occurrence of comname conditional on oversea==1 and start with zero:

```
mydata[oversea==1, mycount := match(year, unique(year))-1, comname];mydata
```

i hope to get  mycount=hopecount ,but mycount will be NA when oversea==0

is there any way to let oversea==0  "no count" and fill in "previous count time" instead of "NA".
just like the  form of hopecount

thx alot ^^"

Comment: Extending my answer to your previous question, you could use `mydata[, mycount := cumsum(!duplicated(year) & oversea == 1) - 1L, by = comname]`

Comment: You're defining the vars at the (comname, year) level. In my opinion, better to make a table at that level, like `comyear = unique(mydata[oversea == 1, .(comname, year)])[, v := rowid(comname) - 1L ][]` or something, and not bother merging the vars back to `mydata` until needed.

Comment: @docendodiscimus, may i ask the function of  "-1L"? one time lag? or something. thx

Comment: @changix `- 1L` means simple substraction of 1 (as an integer). `1` is double and `1L` is integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `na.locf` from `zoo` to replace the NA elements with the previous non-NA adjacent element

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
mydata[oversea==1, hopecount2 := match(year, unique(year))-1, comname
          ][, hopecount2 := na.locf(hopecount2), comname]
identical(mydata$hopecount, mydata$hopecount2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Or `mydata[, v := cumsum(oversea)-1, by=comname][]`. Oh, nvm, OP broke that with their edit.

Comment: @Frank, I believe the counting is also related to the year column as in OP's previous question

Comment: @docendo Yeah, my suggestion just happened to work for the OP's initial example, since edited so year matters.